# Elasticsearch query: Fetch all the results which prefix matches the query for typeahead, autocomplete feature

Tags: elasticsearch, search, autocomplete, lucene, elk

| query |
| --- |
| what is my name |
| what is google |
| what is stackoverflow |
| how to search |

So, I would like to have an Elasticsearch Index which has documents as above. I would like to fetch all the results which prefix matches the query. For example, when queried for "what is", I need {"what is my name", "what is google", "what is stackoverflow"} as results, exact prefix match.

How do I go about creating an index? and Example queries, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [multiple ways](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/elasticsearch-auto-complete-guide/) to achieve what you want, but simplest is to use the [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html), if you just index your data directly to Elasticsearch without defining mapping, it will automatically create two fields for you, and on `.keyword` field you can use the prefix query as shown below.

**Index sample documents**

```
PUT <your-es-index>/_doc/1

{
    "title" : "what is my name"
}

PUT <your-es-index>/_doc/2

{
    "title" : "what is google"
}

PUT <your-es-index>/_doc/3

{
    "title" : "what is stackoverflow"
}

PUT <your-es-index>/_doc/4

{
    "title" : "how to search"
}
```

**Search query**

POST /_search

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "title.keyword": {
                "value": "what is"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Your expected search results**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "72391510",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "what is my name"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "72391510",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "what is google"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "72391510",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "what is stackoverflow"
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hey Amit, Thanks for answering. This approach doesn't work well in few cases. For example, lets say I have {"my town", "where is my town"} as documents and when I try to search "my", I do not want "where is my town" in my search results. I need a strict prefix match. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Sukeesh thanks for getting back to me, my query is **strict prefix** query, but looks like instead of `keyword` you are querying the`text` datatype. please pay attention to field i am searching in my example it has `.keyword`.

Comment: Worked. Thanks, I have accepted your answer.